# Getting variable inside click event Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm using Google maps, I'm trying to access a variable inside a function but I don't know how.

```
 if(navigator.geolocation) {

    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
     // map.setCenter(initialLocation);
       markerL = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: initialLocation,
                       map: map,
                        title: "You are Here",
                    });

                     markerL.setMap(map);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });

  }
```

I want to access initalLocation here

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

     var request = {
       origin: window.initialLocation, 
       destination: 'london',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
     });
```

Firebug tells me initalLocation is undefined.
Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Have you noticed the typo init*i*alLocation? That's not in your code though..

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the value like this:

```
window.initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
```

I.e. always use the `window.` prefix.

Please note that using the window object for keeping global variables is not the best programming practice. If your script is small, that's OK though.

Comment: No that hasn't done it mate, I still get this error Error: Invalid value for property <origin>: undefined
[Break On This Error]  

...?m:Td(this.lat(),a.lat())&&Td(this.lng(),a.lng())};R[H].equals=R[H].G;R[H].lat=Z.

Comment: Could it be that the js compilation/mimification makes the code unusable? Have you tried disabling js compilation?

Comment: I wouldn't know what that is :)

Answer (score 0):

the callback of `geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` will be called asynchronously, therefore you cannot access the variable before the callback has been executed.

**Solution:** invoke the directionsService-request in the callback of `getCurrentPosition()`

Comment: That was my initial approach, it worked. I just thought it wasn't the best practice. There's also another reason where I will likely need to start a new question just to explain it.